# How can I filter a multi-line pattern across a text file with bash, only using grep, awk and/or sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I have a collection of big files (around 5 million words), each made by xgrepping some patterns from a few XML files from PubMed. I used `xgrep -tx "//PMID|//ArticleTitle|//Abstract|//MeshHeadingList"`, so I have all the lines that contain these specific XML tags.

But some of the articles don't have the `<Abstract></Abstract>` tag, and I need to filter those out for a college assignment.

I have a solution using pcregrep: `pcregrep -M '<PMID.*</PMID>\n<ArticleTitle>.*</ArticleTitle>\n<Abstract>.*</Abstract>\n<MeshHeadingList>.*</MeshHeadingList>\n' xgrep.txt` gives me the correct output in a split-second. The problem is that pcregrep isn't installed in my Uni's PCs, so when they review my scripts it's not gonna work.

Using only grep (`grep -Pazo '<PMID.*</PMID>\n<ArticleTitle>.*</ArticleTitle>\n<Abstract>.*</Abstract>\n<MeshHeadingList>.*</MeshHeadingList>\n' xgrep.txt`) I do achieve the same result, but it takes an absurd amount of time -- around 14-15 minutes. How can I make this work in a reasonable time with only default bash commands? -- **Update:** as requested in comments, OS is Linux Mint LMDE 5 (Elsie). Bash version is 5.1.4.

Simply using awk's `/start-pattern/,/end-pattern/` doesn't work, because all of the file's articles begin and end with the same pattern (`<PMID>` and `</MeshHeadingList>`, respectively). Maybe there's a more advanced option for awk I could use that I don't know about.

**Update:**

Example from the xgrep.txt file:

```xml
<PMID Version="1">19</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>Antidepressant drugs affect dopamine uptake.</ArticleTitle>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000928" MajorTopicYN="N">Antidepressive Agents</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="Y">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D001921" MajorTopicYN="N">Brain</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000378" MajorTopicYN="N">metabolism</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000697" MajorTopicYN="N">Central Nervous System Stimulants</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003864" MajorTopicYN="N">Depression, Chemical</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004298" MajorTopicYN="N">Dopamine</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000378" MajorTopicYN="Y">metabolism</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D066298" MajorTopicYN="N">In Vitro Techniques</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D008297" MajorTopicYN="N">Male</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D051381" MajorTopicYN="N">Rats</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
<PMID Version="1">20</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>Aggregation of blood platelets by adrenaline and its uptake.</ArticleTitle>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D001792" MajorTopicYN="N">Blood Platelets</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000378" MajorTopicYN="Y">metabolism</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004087" MajorTopicYN="N">Dihydroergotamine</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004347" MajorTopicYN="N">Drug Interactions</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004837" MajorTopicYN="N">Epinephrine</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000097" MajorTopicYN="N">blood</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="Y">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D066298" MajorTopicYN="N">In Vitro Techniques</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D008238" MajorTopicYN="N">Lysergic Acid Diethylamide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D010974" MajorTopicYN="N">Platelet Aggregation</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D011817" MajorTopicYN="N">Rabbits</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
<PMID Version="1">22</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>[Demonstration of tumor inhibiting properties of a strongly immunostimulating low-molecular weight substance. Comparative studies with ifosfamide on the immuno-labile DS carcinosarcoma. Stimulation of the autoimmune activity for approx. 20 days by BA 1, a N-(2-cyanoethylene)-urea. Novel prophylactic possibilities].</ArticleTitle>
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>A report is given on the recent discovery of outstanding immunological properties in BA 1 [N-(2-cyanoethylene)-urea] having a (low) molecular mass M = 111.104. Experiments in 214 DS carcinosarcoma bearing Wistar rats have shown that BA 1, at a dosage of only about 12 percent LD50 (150 mg kg) and negligible lethality (1.7 percent), results in a recovery rate of 40 percent without hyperglycemia and, in one test, of 80 percent with hyperglycemia. Under otherwise unchanged conditions the reference substance ifosfamide (IF) -- a further development of cyclophosphamide -- applied without hyperglycemia in its most efficient dosage of 47 percent LD50 (150 mg kg) brought about a recovery rate of 25 percent at a lethality of 18 percent. (Contrary to BA 1, 250-min hyperglycemia caused no further improvement of the recovery rate.) However this comparison is characterized by the fact that both substances exhibit two quite different (complementary) mechanisms of action. Leucocyte counts made after application of the said cancerostatics and dosages have shown a pronounced stimulation with BA 1 and with ifosfamide, the known suppression in the post-therapeutic interval usually found with standard cancerostatics. In combination with the cited plaque test for BA 1, blood pictures then allow conclusions on the immunity status. Since IF can be taken as one of the most efficient cancerostatics--there is no other chemotherapeutic known up to now that has a more significant effect on the DS carcinosarcoma in rats -- these findings are of special importance. Finally, the total amount of leucocytes and lymphocytes as well as their time behaviour was determined from the blood picture of tumour-free rats after i.v. application of BA 1. The thus obtained numerical values clearly show that further research work on the prophylactic use of this substance seems to be necessary and very promising.</AbstractText>         </Abstract>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000970" MajorTopicYN="N">Antineoplastic Agents</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="Y">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D002296" MajorTopicYN="N">Carcinosarcoma</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000188" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug therapy</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003520" MajorTopicYN="N">Cyclophosphamide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000031" MajorTopicYN="Y">analogs &amp; derivatives</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004353" MajorTopicYN="N">Drug Evaluation, Preclinical</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004361" MajorTopicYN="N">Drug Tolerance</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004906" MajorTopicYN="N">Erythrocyte Count</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006863" MajorTopicYN="N">Hydrogen-Ion Concentration</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006943" MajorTopicYN="N">Hyperglycemia</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007069" MajorTopicYN="Y">Ifosfamide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="N">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007109" MajorTopicYN="N">Immunity</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007165" MajorTopicYN="N">Immunosuppression Therapy</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007928" MajorTopicYN="N">Lethal Dose 50</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007958" MajorTopicYN="N">Leukocyte Count</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D008297" MajorTopicYN="N">Male</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D051379" MajorTopicYN="N">Mice</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D009374" MajorTopicYN="N">Neoplasms, Experimental</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000188" MajorTopicYN="N">drug therapy</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D051381" MajorTopicYN="N">Rats</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D013268" MajorTopicYN="N">Stimulation, Chemical</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D013997" MajorTopicYN="N">Time Factors</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D014508" MajorTopicYN="N">Urea</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000031" MajorTopicYN="Y">analogs &amp; derivatives</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="N">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
<PMID Version="1">23</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>Effect of etafenone on total and regional myocardial blood flow.</ArticleTitle>
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>The distribution of blood flow to the subendocardial, medium and subepicardial layers of the left ventricular free wall was studied in anaesthetized dogs under normoxic (A), hypoxic (B) conditions and under pharmacologically induced (etafenone) coronary vasodilation (C). Regional myocardial blood flow was determined by means of the particle distribution method. In normoxia a transmural gradient of flow was observed, with the subendocardial layers receiving a significantly higher flow rate compared with the subepicardial layers. In hypoxia induced vasodilation this transmural gradient of flow was persistent. In contrast a marked redistribution of regional flow was observed under pharmacologically induced vasodilation. The transmural gradient decreased. In contrast to some findings these experiments demonstrate that a considerable vasodilatory capacity exists in all layers of the myocardium and can be utilized by drugs. The differences observed for the intramural distribution pattern of flow under hypoxia and drug induced vasodilation support the hypothesis that this pattern reflects corresponding gradients of regional myocardial metabolism.</AbstractText>         </Abstract>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D001794" MajorTopicYN="N">Blood Pressure</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D002245" MajorTopicYN="N">Carbon Dioxide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000097" MajorTopicYN="N">blood</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D002302" MajorTopicYN="N">Cardiac Output</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003326" MajorTopicYN="N">Coronary Circulation</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003331" MajorTopicYN="N">Coronary Vessels</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004285" MajorTopicYN="N">Dogs</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006339" MajorTopicYN="N">Heart Rate</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006346" MajorTopicYN="N">Heart Septum</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006352" MajorTopicYN="N">Heart Ventricles</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006863" MajorTopicYN="N">Hydrogen-Ion Concentration</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000860" MajorTopicYN="N">Hypoxia</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000503" MajorTopicYN="N">physiopathology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D010100" MajorTopicYN="N">Oxygen</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000097" MajorTopicYN="N">blood</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D011427" MajorTopicYN="N">Propiophenones</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="Y">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D014665" MajorTopicYN="N">Vasodilator Agents</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="Y">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
```

Desired output:

```xml
<PMID Version="1">22</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>[Demonstration of tumor inhibiting properties of a strongly immunostimulating low-molecular weight substance. Comparative studies with ifosfamide on the immuno-labile DS carcinosarcoma. Stimulation of the autoimmune activity for approx. 20 days by BA 1, a N-(2-cyanoethylene)-urea. Novel prophylactic possibilities].</ArticleTitle>
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>A report is given on the recent discovery of outstanding immunological properties in BA 1 [N-(2-cyanoethylene)-urea] having a (low) molecular mass M = 111.104. Experiments in 214 DS carcinosarcoma bearing Wistar rats have shown that BA 1, at a dosage of only about 12 percent LD50 (150 mg kg) and negligible lethality (1.7 percent), results in a recovery rate of 40 percent without hyperglycemia and, in one test, of 80 percent with hyperglycemia. Under otherwise unchanged conditions the reference substance ifosfamide (IF) -- a further development of cyclophosphamide -- applied without hyperglycemia in its most efficient dosage of 47 percent LD50 (150 mg kg) brought about a recovery rate of 25 percent at a lethality of 18 percent. (Contrary to BA 1, 250-min hyperglycemia caused no further improvement of the recovery rate.) However this comparison is characterized by the fact that both substances exhibit two quite different (complementary) mechanisms of action. Leucocyte counts made after application of the said cancerostatics and dosages have shown a pronounced stimulation with BA 1 and with ifosfamide, the known suppression in the post-therapeutic interval usually found with standard cancerostatics. In combination with the cited plaque test for BA 1, blood pictures then allow conclusions on the immunity status. Since IF can be taken as one of the most efficient cancerostatics--there is no other chemotherapeutic known up to now that has a more significant effect on the DS carcinosarcoma in rats -- these findings are of special importance. Finally, the total amount of leucocytes and lymphocytes as well as their time behaviour was determined from the blood picture of tumour-free rats after i.v. application of BA 1. The thus obtained numerical values clearly show that further research work on the prophylactic use of this substance seems to be necessary and very promising.</AbstractText>         </Abstract>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000970" MajorTopicYN="N">Antineoplastic Agents</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="Y">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D002296" MajorTopicYN="N">Carcinosarcoma</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000188" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug therapy</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003520" MajorTopicYN="N">Cyclophosphamide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000031" MajorTopicYN="Y">analogs &amp; derivatives</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004353" MajorTopicYN="N">Drug Evaluation, Preclinical</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004361" MajorTopicYN="N">Drug Tolerance</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004906" MajorTopicYN="N">Erythrocyte Count</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006863" MajorTopicYN="N">Hydrogen-Ion Concentration</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006943" MajorTopicYN="N">Hyperglycemia</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007069" MajorTopicYN="Y">Ifosfamide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="N">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007109" MajorTopicYN="N">Immunity</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007165" MajorTopicYN="N">Immunosuppression Therapy</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007928" MajorTopicYN="N">Lethal Dose 50</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007958" MajorTopicYN="N">Leukocyte Count</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D008297" MajorTopicYN="N">Male</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D051379" MajorTopicYN="N">Mice</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D009374" MajorTopicYN="N">Neoplasms, Experimental</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000188" MajorTopicYN="N">drug therapy</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D051381" MajorTopicYN="N">Rats</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D013268" MajorTopicYN="N">Stimulation, Chemical</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D013997" MajorTopicYN="N">Time Factors</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D014508" MajorTopicYN="N">Urea</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000031" MajorTopicYN="Y">analogs &amp; derivatives</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="N">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
<PMID Version="1">23</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>Effect of etafenone on total and regional myocardial blood flow.</ArticleTitle>
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>The distribution of blood flow to the subendocardial, medium and subepicardial layers of the left ventricular free wall was studied in anaesthetized dogs under normoxic (A), hypoxic (B) conditions and under pharmacologically induced (etafenone) coronary vasodilation (C). Regional myocardial blood flow was determined by means of the particle distribution method. In normoxia a transmural gradient of flow was observed, with the subendocardial layers receiving a significantly higher flow rate compared with the subepicardial layers. In hypoxia induced vasodilation this transmural gradient of flow was persistent. In contrast a marked redistribution of regional flow was observed under pharmacologically induced vasodilation. The transmural gradient decreased. In contrast to some findings these experiments demonstrate that a considerable vasodilatory capacity exists in all layers of the myocardium and can be utilized by drugs. The differences observed for the intramural distribution pattern of flow under hypoxia and drug induced vasodilation support the hypothesis that this pattern reflects corresponding gradients of regional myocardial metabolism.</AbstractText>         </Abstract>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D001794" MajorTopicYN="N">Blood Pressure</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D002245" MajorTopicYN="N">Carbon Dioxide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000097" MajorTopicYN="N">blood</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D002302" MajorTopicYN="N">Cardiac Output</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003326" MajorTopicYN="N">Coronary Circulation</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003331" MajorTopicYN="N">Coronary Vessels</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004285" MajorTopicYN="N">Dogs</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006339" MajorTopicYN="N">Heart Rate</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="N">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006346" MajorTopicYN="N">Heart Septum</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006352" MajorTopicYN="N">Heart Ventricles</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006863" MajorTopicYN="N">Hydrogen-Ion Concentration</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000860" MajorTopicYN="N">Hypoxia</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000503" MajorTopicYN="N">physiopathology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D010100" MajorTopicYN="N">Oxygen</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000097" MajorTopicYN="N">blood</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D011427" MajorTopicYN="N">Propiophenones</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="Y">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D014665" MajorTopicYN="N">Vasodilator Agents</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="Y">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
```

Comment: It'd help if you could provide a [mre] including some example input and desired output, plus the exact awk command you ran.

Comment: please update the question with a sample from `xgrep.txt`; ~20 lines should be sufficient, just make sure it includes some lines to keep and some lines to remove; then update the question to show the (wrong) output generated by your `grep` and `awk` attempts along with the (correct) expected output ... making sure all sets of output correspond to the sample input

Comment: Sample input is **required here**

Comment: `grep` only processes one line at a time, you can't use it for multiline patterns.

Comment: @Barmar: it can do it if you ask him (hack) or use `pcregrep -M`. Anyway, `XML` parsing is better done with `xmllint` `xmlstarlet` or `xidel`

Comment: @markp-fuso just updated the post. I didn't actually try any awk commands because I don't know which pattern I should use. The grep I used did work correctly, it just took way too long.

Comment: What are "default bash commands"?  There are certainly some standards that specify which utilities you can expect to have available; which one are you referring to?

Comment: @WilliamPursell True. OS is Linux Mint LMDE 5 (Elsie). Bash version is 5.1.4. I'm not sure exactly what packages are available, but not many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/<PMID|>\[|<Abstract/{N;/>\[|<Abstract|<MeshHeadingList/p;}' input_file
<PMID Version="1">21</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>[Biochemical studies on camomile components/III. In vitro studies about the antipeptic activity of (--)-alpha-bisabolol (author's transl)].</ArticleTitle>
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>(--)-alpha-Bisabolol has a primary antipeptic action depending on dosage, which is not caused by an alteration of the pH-value. The proteolytic activity of pepsin is reduced by 50 percent through addition of bisabolol in the ratio of 1/0.5. The antipeptic action of bisabolol only occurs in case of direct contact. In case of a previous contact with the substrate, the inhibiting effect is lost.</AbstractText>         </Abstract>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004305" MajorTopicYN="N">Dose-Response Relationship, Drug</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006454" MajorTopicYN="N">Hemoglobins</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000378" MajorTopicYN="N">metabolism</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006863" MajorTopicYN="N">Hydrogen-Ion Concentration</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D066298" MajorTopicYN="N">In Vitro Techniques</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D008722" MajorTopicYN="N">Methods</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D010434" MajorTopicYN="N">Pepsin A</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000037" MajorTopicYN="Y">antagonists &amp; inhibitors</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000378" MajorTopicYN="N">metabolism</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D010946" MajorTopicYN="N">Plants, Medicinal</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D012717" MajorTopicYN="N">Sesquiterpenes</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="Y">pharmacology</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D013056" MajorTopicYN="N">Spectrophotometry, Ultraviolet</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D014238" MajorTopicYN="N">Trichloroacetic Acid</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D014443" MajorTopicYN="N">Tyrosine</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000378" MajorTopicYN="N">metabolism</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
<PMID Version="1">22</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>[Demonstration of tumor inhibiting properties of a strongly immunostimulating low-molecular weight substance. Comparative studies with ifosfamide on the immuno-labile DS carcinosarcoma. Stimulation of the autoimmune activity for approx. 20 days by BA 1, a N-(2-cyanoethylene)-urea. Novel prophylactic possibilities].</ArticleTitle>
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>A report is given on the recent discovery of outstanding immunological properties in BA 1 [N-(2-cyanoethylene)-urea] having a (low) molecular mass M = 111.104. Experiments in 214 DS carcinosarcoma bearing Wistar rats have shown that BA 1, at a dosage of only about 12 percent LD50 (150 mg kg) and negligible lethality (1.7 percent), results in a recovery rate of 40 percent without hyperglycemia and, in one test, of 80 percent with hyperglycemia. Under otherwise unchanged conditions the reference substance ifosfamide (IF) -- a further development of cyclophosphamide -- applied without hyperglycemia in its most efficient dosage of 47 percent LD50 (150 mg kg) brought about a recovery rate of 25 percent at a lethality of 18 percent. (Contrary to BA 1, 250-min hyperglycemia caused no further improvement of the recovery rate.) However this comparison is characterized by the fact that both substances exhibit two quite different (complementary) mechanisms of action. Leucocyte counts made after application of the said cancerostatics and dosages have shown a pronounced stimulation with BA 1 and with ifosfamide, the known suppression in the post-therapeutic interval usually found with standard cancerostatics. In combination with the cited plaque test for BA 1, blood pictures then allow conclusions on the immunity status. Since IF can be taken as one of the most efficient cancerostatics--there is no other chemotherapeutic known up to now that has a more significant effect on the DS carcinosarcoma in rats -- these findings are of special importance. Finally, the total amount of leucocytes and lymphocytes as well as their time behaviour was determined from the blood picture of tumour-free rats after i.v. application of BA 1. The thus obtained numerical values clearly show that further research work on the prophylactic use of this substance seems to be necessary and very promising.</AbstractText>         </Abstract>
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D000970" MajorTopicYN="N">Antineoplastic Agents</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="Y">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D002296" MajorTopicYN="N">Carcinosarcoma</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000188" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug therapy</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D003520" MajorTopicYN="N">Cyclophosphamide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000031" MajorTopicYN="Y">analogs &amp; derivatives</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004353" MajorTopicYN="N">Drug Evaluation, Preclinical</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004361" MajorTopicYN="N">Drug Tolerance</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D004906" MajorTopicYN="N">Erythrocyte Count</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006863" MajorTopicYN="N">Hydrogen-Ion Concentration</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D006943" MajorTopicYN="N">Hyperglycemia</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007069" MajorTopicYN="Y">Ifosfamide</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="N">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007109" MajorTopicYN="N">Immunity</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000187" MajorTopicYN="Y">drug effects</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007165" MajorTopicYN="N">Immunosuppression Therapy</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007928" MajorTopicYN="N">Lethal Dose 50</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D007958" MajorTopicYN="N">Leukocyte Count</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D008297" MajorTopicYN="N">Male</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D051379" MajorTopicYN="N">Mice</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D009374" MajorTopicYN="N">Neoplasms, Experimental</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000188" MajorTopicYN="N">drug therapy</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D051381" MajorTopicYN="N">Rats</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D013268" MajorTopicYN="N">Stimulation, Chemical</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D013997" MajorTopicYN="N">Time Factors</DescriptorName>         </MeshHeading>         <MeshHeading>           <DescriptorName UI="D014508" MajorTopicYN="N">Urea</DescriptorName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000031" MajorTopicYN="Y">analogs &amp; derivatives</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000494" MajorTopicYN="N">pharmacology</QualifierName>           <QualifierName UI="Q000627" MajorTopicYN="N">therapeutic use</QualifierName>         </MeshHeading>       </MeshHeadingList>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the article title is not surrounded by square brackets, and I only now realized both examples I provided had those. But not all of them do, sorry.

Comment: So, I was able to adapt your answer to my problem, had to learn more about regexes (great!). What I ended up with was `sed -En '/\<PMID\>/ {N; /\<ArticleTitle\>/ {N; /\<Abstract>/ {N; /\<MeshHeadingList\>/ p;} } }' xgrep.txt`, which solves the problem very quickly, although can probably be improved length-wise. Thank you for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- all lines start with one of four patterns: `<PMID`, `<ArticleTitle`, `<Abstract` or `<MeshHeadingList`
- each 'block' of text will have no more than four lines, with each of the (previously mentioned) patterns occurring no more than once in a block
- only print (to stdout) those blocks that contain four lines (and thus contain each of the four patterns)
- the first line in a block will always start with `<PMID`

Cutting the sample down to something a bit more manageable:

```
$ cut -c1-50 xgrep.txt > xgrep.short.txt
$ cat xgrep.short.txt

<PMID Version="1">19</PMID>                             # discard
<ArticleTitle>Antidepressant drugs affect dopamine      # discard
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>                 # discard

<PMID Version="1">20</PMID>                             # discard
<ArticleTitle>Aggregation of blood platelets by ad      # discard
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>                 # discard

<PMID Version="1">22</PMID>                             # keep
<ArticleTitle>[Demonstration of tumor inhibiting p      # keep
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>A report is giv      # keep
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>                 # keep

<PMID Version="1">23</PMID>                             # keep
<ArticleTitle>Effect of etafenone on total and reg      # keep
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>The distributio      # keep
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>                 # keep
```

**NOTE:** comments and blank lines added for clarification; the comments and blank lines do not exist in the file (`xgrep.short.txt`)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function print_block() { 
    if (linecnt==4)
       print block
    linecnt=0
    block=""
}
/^(<PMID|<ArticleTitle|<Abstract|<MeshHeading)/ { 
    if ($0 ~ /^<PMID/)                                 # flush previous block to stdout?
       print_block()
    linecnt++
    block = block (block!="" ? RS : "" ) $0
}
END  { print_block() }                                 # flush last block to stdout?
' xgrep.short.txt
```

This generates:

```
<PMID Version="1">22</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>[Demonstration of tumor inhibiting p
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>A report is giv
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>

<PMID Version="1">23</PMID>
<ArticleTitle>Effect of etafenone on total and reg
<Abstract>           <AbstractText>The distributio
<MeshHeadingList>         <MeshHeading>
```

**NOTE:** blank line added for readability; blank line is not part of actual output

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^<PMID/{:a;N;/^<MeshHeadingList/M!ba;/^<Abstract>/Mp}' file
```

Filter file using the option `-n` to print only the collection of lines that start with `<PMID` and end with a line starting `<MeshHeadingList` and contain a line starting `<Abstract>`.

N.B. The `M` flag when matching a regexp operates on multiple lines and allow the `^` and `$` to match start and end of lines.